# Entity Framework fetch Top 10 rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a 3 tables in SQL database

**tblVideos**:

```
VideoID     int PK
Title       varchar(100)
Decription  varchar(100)
```

**tblTags**:

```
TagID       int PK
TagText     varchar(100)
```

**tblVideosToTags**:

```
VideoID     int PK, FK to Videos
TagID       int PK, FK to Tags
```

In Entity Framework (v6-latest-nightly-build) I have 2 classes `Video` and `Tag` with many-to-many relationships. I need a help with building a LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL query which meets following conditions:

Top 10 records from Tags, which is mostly used. So probably some summing/count/grouping needed

Comment: What's the query you've created so far?

Comment: actually I'm stucked at the begining: db.Tags.Include(x => x.Videos).OrderBy(... here I need some ideas

Comment: Linq-to-SQL is a **different**, simplistic ORM - so you're ***either*** using Entity Framework (then you'll be writing Linq-to-Entities queries), ***OR*** you're using Linq-to-SQL - but those are two totally separate, different pieces of code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you wanted to find the top 10 Videos with the most number of Tags, you would probably find it easier, but in fact what you want to do now is exactly the same. You just need the top 10 Tags with the most number of Videos. Use this:

```
var mostUsedTags = db.Tags.OrderByDescending(t => t.Videos.Count).Take(10);
```

Comment: Once more question. What if I want to add lang column to Videos table and want do the same, but with filter by language (fetch top 10 mostly used tags from videos with specified language). Something like: var mostUsedTags = db.Tags.OrderByDescending(t => t.Videos.Where(l => l.Lang == lang).Count).Take(10); But this construction is not working

Comment: Use this:

`db.Tags.OrderByDescending(t => t.Videos.Count(v => v.Lang == lang)).Take(10);`

Comment: Hi ataravati, need your help once again. Trying to get tags for last 3 uploaded videos with no luck...

Comment: Assuming that VideoID is an auto-generated ID, the last uploaded video is the one with the maximum VideoID. So, here is what you need to do: `var tags = db.Videos.OrderByDescending(v => v.VideoID).Take(3).Select(v => v.Tags).SelectMany(t => t).Distinct();` You need to use Distinct() to get rid of duplicate tags.

Comment: And, you use SelectMany to flatten IEnumerable<T> into T.