# Query generated by EF takes too much time to execute

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a very simple query which is generated by Entity-Framework, ***Sometimes*** when I try to run this query It almost takes more than 30 seconds to be executed, and I got time out `Exception`.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate], 
[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount], 
[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId], 
[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus], 
[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId], 
[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
FROM ( SELECT [Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID], [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], [Extent1].[Url] AS [Url], [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], [Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate], [Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount], [Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId], [Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus], [Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId], [Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Links] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC
```

And the code which is generating the Query is:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<TEntity>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        return query;
    });
}
```

Note that when I remove inner `Select` statement and `Where` clause and change it to following, Query executes fine in a less than a second.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
.
.
.
FROM [dbo].[Links] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC
```

Any advice will be helpful.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the usage of Above code:

```
var dbLinks = await _uow.LinkRespository.GetAsync(filter, orderBy);
var pagedLinks = new PagedList<Link>(dbLinks, pageNumber, PAGE_SIZE);
var vmLinks = Mapper.Map<IPagedList<LinkViewItemViewModel>>(pagedLinks);
```

And filter:

```
var result = await GetLinks(null, pageNo, a => a.OrderByDescending(x => x.SentDate));
```

Comment: `WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0` this is always going to be more than 0, why would you do that?

Comment: Do what? I omit the `WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0` in Sql Server Management studio, not in code. I didn't touch my code.

Comment: I just wanted to say that having Row_number > 0 will not affect your result set at all and it could be slowing down your query. Just a opinion from SQL Server side, i know nothing about EF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes you are right, now I'm looking for how to omit that from generated query.

Comment: Would that help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493132/entity-framework-fetch-top-10-rows

Comment: My first port of call would be the query analyser in SQL Server. Try looking for a component where the *estimated number of rows* is vastly different from the *actual number of rows*, because that implies the compiler has picked the wrong kind of join (nested vs. hash join) for the inner query.

Comment: @saber Basically, [you don't want to use Task.Run for work that is not CPU-bound](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html).

Comment: It seems to me like the inner query is a bigger issue than the comparator at the end but I have no evidence.  But, intuitively, you are selecting the entire set, then selecting the top ten from that, rather than just picking the top ten.  So if this is a large table the performance issue seems obvious.

Comment: Sorry, It's just that half the stuff I do nowadays seems to be 'strip out EF because it's non-performant' and this question boils down to 'my generic query maker which runs on top of a third party generic query maker sometimes creates non-performant queries'. If there is a 'rearrange your linq to this, for this type of query' solution, does it really solve your issue other than being a work around?

Comment: I mean if you add if(filter == wouldProduceNonPerfQuery) { filter = replacement filter) is that really that differnt from if(filter == x) { exec proc instead}

Comment: @emodendroket No, the problem is comparator at the end. Inner query is not a big deal. I still have a performance problem even if I omit the inner statement. but without comparator query runs in less than a second over 50000 record.

Comment: @saber OK, well, I suppose that's the benefit of doing empirical tests.  Sorry.

Comment: @emodendroket The interesting thing is it doesn't happen all the time, Just sometimes.

Comment: It seems to me the bad thing about this query is the order by sentdate. I presume sentdate is not unique and therefore the rowcount function will possibly return different results each time you run the query. this invalidates the pagination. when you ask for page 2 some results which were previously on page 2 will be moved to page 1.

Comment: re: 'sometimes slow' its clear that the query will run slower for high page numbers vs low ones. However unless you have vast amounts of data prob not for 30sec. Such a long and occasional delay is symptomatic of a locking issue. perhaps adding a row during the query?

Comment: My suggestion to solve these issies is to restrict the volume of data searched by adding an additonal where clause. say just look at one day at a time. Further once the data volume is restricted to a known size, abandon the sql pagination, return the full dataset and paginate in memory (cache as required)

Comment: Alternativley using an autoinc int pk (although I normaly hate these) on the table instead of sent date would allow the server to optimise. If you only add rows in order of sent date and have large vol of data which must be paginatied over this might be a good solution

Comment: does it have the same problem if you remove the `async`/`await` and run it synchronously?

Comment: @saber Have you identified the scenario when the query takes too much time?

Comment: The sub query is what's being used for the pagination. What version of the PageList nuget package are you using? Looks like whatever it's adding to EF when the query is being generated isn't as good as it should be. @Vladimir Baranov's answer talks about a better way to do it. Maybe you should share that / log a bug with the people that built the PagedLists.

Comment: PagedList uses the .skip() and .take undercovers. you could have used dbLinks.skip((pageNumber - 1) * PAGE_SIZE).take(PAGE_SIZE). This still leaves you with a horrible inner select with ROW_COUNT.

Comment: The T-SQL is totally fine. This is a SQL query tuning problem. Post the actual execution plan of a slow execution as XML. Since 99.999% of the execution time is spent server-side the client cannot possibly be at fault. Paging is also fine. It is clearly visible in the SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the `WHERE row_number > 0` will change over time as you ask for page 2, page 3, etc...

As such, I'm curious if it would help to create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_links_SentDate_desc ON [dbo].[Links] ([SentDate] DESC)
```

In all honesty, IF it works, it's pretty much a band-aid and you'll probably will need to rebuild this index on a frequent basis as I'm guessing it will get fragmented over time...

*UPDATE*: check the comments! Turns out the `DESC` has no effect whatsoever and should be avoided if your data comes in low to high!

Comment: EF has an `Index` attribute as well.

Comment: I created the Index, As I explained in post, I'm not frequently getting this exception, Just let me sure this is an correct answer.

Comment: Assuming you do CodeFirst than you could add something like `[Index("idx_links_SentDate_desc", Direction.Ascending)]` to the SentDate field/property. I'm not sure about the `Direction` part though, seems to be missing in the documentation although it is 'kind of hinted at' here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2231176-indexattribute . Googleing around I get quite a bit of unanswered SO questions. There are some 'workarounds' for the migration part though. But as a test, doing supra in SQL should show if it's actually worth the hassle.

Comment: FYI: Initially I tried this on a small table and did not see any change as the query seemed to prefer doing a tables-scan regardless, which can happen on small tables. Out of curiosity I tried it on a big table and it seems the Query Optimizer doesn't really care about the descending index =/ Even when forcing it to make use of it the net effect is zero. Conclusion, although an additional (##) index IS useful, its sort-order doesn't seem to matter. (##: if the field already is a 'leading' part of the PK or a UQ or another index then adding another one won't bring much to the table I fear).

Comment: @deroby :D thanks for your effort, now what? Any other advice?

Comment: I'd still give the index on that field a try, it makes a (big) difference on large tables. And since the order doesn't matter to MSSQL you can do as @emodendroket suggests. (assuming Code First approach) Added bonus is that `SendDate` data probably comes in sequentially so the index will not get fragmented over time due to page-splits.

Comment: @saber I would agree with this, when I've tried this on a large table, having an index on the orderby field has made a big difference.

Comment: @deroby Thanks for your answer, base on idea from your solution I started to reading much more about query performance and also I analyzed my queries and soon I found out I should set another Indexes to other Fields. Others have almost preferred the same solution, But yours was the **First**.

Comment: I have my days, occasionally =) Anyway, I'm going to add a little update to the answer as to point out that the order of the index doesn't seem to matter so if your data comes in sequentially (low to high) then the `DESC` is a bad idea. Hmm.. I'll just add that there is more in the comments...  thx for the points and good luck with the application!

Answer (score 9):

It never occurred to me that you simply didn't have an index. Lesson learnt - always check the basics before digging further.

---

If you don't need pagination, then the query can be simplified to

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    ...
FROM [dbo].[Links] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC
```

and it runs fast, as you've verified.

Apparently, you do need the pagination, so let's see what we can do.

The reason why your current version is slow, because it scans the **whole** table first, calculates row number for each and every row and only then returns 10 rows. **I was wrong here.** SQL Server optimizer is pretty smart. **The root of your problem is somewhere else. See my update below.**

---

BTW, as other people mentioned, this pagination will work correctly only if `SentDate` column is unique. If it is not unique, you need to `ORDER BY SentDate` and another unique column like some `ID` to resolve ambiguity.

If you don't need ability to jump straight to particular page, but rather always start with page 1, then go to next page, next page and so on, then the proper efficient way to do such pagination is described in this excellent article: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way
The author uses PostgreSQL for illustration, but the technique works for MS SQL Server as well. It boils down to remembering the `ID` of the last row on the shown page and then using this `ID` in the `WHERE` clause with appropriate supporting index to retrieve the next page without scanning all previous rows.

SQL Server 2008 doesn't have a built-in support for pagination, so we'll have to use workaround. I will show one variant that allows to jump straight to a given page and would work fast for first pages, but would become slower and slower for further pages.

You will have these variables (`PageSize`, `PageNumber`) in your C# code. I put them here to illustrate the point.

```
DECLARE @VarPageSize int = 10; -- number of rows in each page
DECLARE @VarPageNumber int = 3; -- page numeration is zero-based

SELECT TOP (@VarPageSize)
    [Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID]
    ,[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    ,[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url]
    ,[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    ,[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate]
    ,[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount]
    ,[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId]
    ,[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus]
    ,[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId]
    ,[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP((@VarPageNumber + 1) * @VarPageSize)
            [Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID]
            ,[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
            ,[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url]
            ,[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
            ,[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate]
            ,[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount]
            ,[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId]
            ,[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus]
            ,[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId]
            ,[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
        FROM [dbo].[Links] AS [Extent1]
        ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC
    ) AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] ASC
;
```

The first page is rows 1 to 10, second page is 11 to 20 and so on.
Let's see how this query works when we try to get the fourth page, i.e. rows 31 to 40. `PageSize=10`, `PageNumber=3`. In the inner query we select first 40 rows. Note, that we **don't** scan the whole table here, we scan only first 40 rows. We don't even need explicit `ROW_NUMBER()`. Then we need to select last 10 rows out of those found 40, so outer query selects `TOP(10)` with `ORDER BY` in the opposite direction. As is this will return rows 40 to 31 in reverse order. You can sort them back into correct order on the client, or add one more outer query, which simply sorts them again by `SentDate DESC`. Like this:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID]
    ,[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    ,[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url]
    ,[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    ,[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate]
    ,[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount]
    ,[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId]
    ,[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus]
    ,[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId]
    ,[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP (@VarPageSize)
            [Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID]
            ,[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
            ,[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url]
            ,[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
            ,[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate]
            ,[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount]
            ,[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId]
            ,[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus]
            ,[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId]
            ,[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
        FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP((@VarPageNumber + 1) * @VarPageSize)
                    [Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID]
                    ,[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
                    ,[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url]
                    ,[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
                    ,[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate]
                    ,[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount]
                    ,[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId]
                    ,[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus]
                    ,[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId]
                    ,[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
                FROM [dbo].[Links] AS [Extent1]
                ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC
            ) AS [Extent1]
        ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] ASC
    ) AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC
```

This query (as original query) would work always correctly only if `SentDate` is unique. If it is not unique, add unique column to the `ORDER BY`. For example, if `LinkID` is unique, then in the inner-most query use `ORDER BY SentDate DESC, LinkID DESC`. In the outer query reverse the order: `ORDER BY SentDate ASC, LinkID ASC`.

Obviously, if you want to jump to page 1000, then the inner query would have to read 10,000 rows, so the further you go, the slower it gets.

In any case, you need to have an index on `SentDate` (or `SentDate, LinkID`) to make it work. Without an index the query would scan the whole table again.

I'm not telling you here how to translate this query to EF, because I don't know. I never used EF. There may be a way. Also, apparently, you can just force it to use actual SQL, rather than trying to play with C# code.

### Update

**Execution plans comparison**

In my database I have a table `EventLogErrors` with 29,477,859 rows and I compared on SQL Server 2008 the query with `ROW_NUMBER` that EF generates and what I suggested here with `TOP`. I tried to retrieve the fourth page 10 rows long. In both cases optimizer was smart enough to read only 40 rows, as you can see from the execution plans. I used a primary key column for ordering and pagination for this test. When I used another indexed column for pagination results were the same, i.e. both variants read only 40 rows. Needless to say, both variants returned results in a fraction of a second.

**Variant with `TOP`**

[image: Variant with TOP]

**Variant with `ROW_NUMBER`**

[image: Variant with ROW_NUMBER]

What it all means is that the root of your problem is somewhere else. You mentioned that your query runs slowly only **sometimes** and I didn't really pay attention to it originally. With such symptom I would do the following:

- Check execution plan.
- Check that you do have an index.
- Check that the index is not heavily fragmented and statistics is not outdated.
- The SQL Server has a feature called [Auto-Parameterization](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175264(v=sql.80).aspx). Also, it has a feature called [Parameter Sniffing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx). Also, it has a feature called [Execution plan caching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx). When all three features work together it may result in using a non-optimal execution plan. There is an excellent article by Erland Sommarskog explaining it in detail: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html This article explains how to confirm that the problem is really in parameter sniffing by checking the cached execution plan and what can be done to fix the problem.

Comment: Although I've always liked the approach above and used this method in the past, I think that with the introduction of `ROW_NUMBER()` you should consider switching to that. Not only because it's (a lot) easier to read, but also because it performs remarkably better once you go into the 'higher pages'! (You have to use `WHERE rn BETWEEN x AND y` though, the `TOP` approach that EF uses is definitely not as efficient, not at all).

Comment: UPDATE: Duh, turns my test was botched and the `TOP` approach EF uses actually **does** outperform the `BETWEEN` syntax I always use. The difference is marginally, but in the end it seems EF does use the better approach available. I'll double check tomorrow, my server currently is under a lot of stress due to a massive rollback, but if things change I'll add another comment.

Comment: @deroby, I compared execution plans for my variant with `TOP` and EF variant with `ROW_NUMBER` and updated my answer. They have very similar performance, because they read same number of rows. For both their performance degrades when you go into the "higher pages". If you want to fetch the page number 10,000, they will both read 100,000 rows. Variant with `ROW_NUMBER` can be slightly faster, because it doesn't use extra `Sort`.

Comment: Thanks for the update with tests! I had done something similar and came to the same conclusion. Strangely, the query plan cost of both queries was pretty much identical (51% vs 49% I believe when run together), yet their execution times (as measured by Sql Sentry Plan Explorer) would go in favour of the `ROW_NUMBER()` approach as the page-nr went up. I'll try to rerun my tests when I can get on 'the big server' again and try to somehow get a screenshot out of it.

Comment: @deroby, plan cost varied depending on whether index is the main clustered PK or some another non-clustered column, but I was looking mainly at the number of reads and number of rows read. It was exactly the same for both variants for low and high page numbers. So, overall, I'd say variant with `ROW_NUMBER` is better from readability point of view and slightly from performance point of view. The main problem now is that query is **sometimes** slow and I've added my thoughts how I would try to solve such problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the inner select can cause problems with the execution plan, but it's the easiest way for the expression tree to be built from the code.  Usually, it won't affect performance too much.

Clearly in this case it does.  One workaround is to use your own query with `ExecuteStoreQuery`.  Something like this:

```
int takeNo = 20;
int skipNo = 100;

var results = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Link>(
    "SELECT LinkID, Title, Url, Description, SentDate, VisitCount, RssSourceId, ReviewStatus, UserAccountId, CreationDate FROM Links", 
    null);

results = results.OrderBy(x=> x.SentDate).Skip(skipNo).Take(takeNo);
```

Of course you lose a lot of the benefits of using an ORM in the first place by doing this, but it might be acceptable for an exceptional circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a standard paging query.  I would guess that you do not have an index on SentDate.  If so, the first thing to try is adding an index on SentDate and seeing what kind of impact this has on performance.  Assuming that you do not always want to sort/page on SentDate and that indexing every column that you might want to sort/page by is not going to happen, take a look at [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383874/ef-sorting-paging-slow-as-ordered-twice).  In some cases, SQL Server's "Gather Streams" parallelism operation can overflow into TempDb.  When this happens, performance goes into the toilet.  As the other answer says, Indexing the column can help, as can disabling parallelism.  Check out your query plan and see if it looks like this might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very good in EF but can give you hints. First of all you have to check if you have an non-clustered index on [Extent1].[SentDate]. Second if not, create, if exists, then recreate or re-arrange it.

Third change your query like this. As your original SQL is nothing just written un-necessary complex and it would result same as this one I am showing here. Try to write things simple, will work faster and maintenance would also be easy.

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate], 
[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount], 
[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId], 
[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus], 
[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId], 
[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
FROM [dbo].[Links] AS [Extent1]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[SentDate] DESC
```

or modify this one little bit like this if case it result different.

```
select top 10 A.* from (
SELECT * from
[Extent1].[LinkID] AS [LinkID], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Url] AS [Url], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[SentDate] AS [SentDate], 
[Extent1].[VisitCount] AS [VisitCount], 
[Extent1].[RssSourceId] AS [RssSourceId], 
[Extent1].[ReviewStatus] AS [ReviewStatus], 
[Extent1].[UserAccountId] AS [UserAccountId], 
[Extent1].[CreationDate] AS [CreationDate]
FROM [dbo].[Links] AS [Extent1] ) A
ORDER BY A.[SentDate] DESC
```

I am 99% sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried chaining in the method?

```
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
        return query.Where(x => (filter != null ? filter : x)
                    .Where(x => (orderBy != null ? orderBy : x));
```

I am wondering if this will change the query that is created by EF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try this, but the problem is this statement `WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 0`, Do you be-leave this will omit the where clause?

Comment: Yes, the inner select statement is really iffy (I do a lot of  SQL development too). The theory is that by moving the entire return to a single statement EF will evaluate it as a single statement rather than try to put the filter in after it creates the query.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would matter... until you call ToList or whatever the query is not actually resolved (and then once it is you're lazy-loading properties, not changing the query) and it's just building up an `Expression` that it will translate into a query.  But hey, I didn't try it.

Comment: @orgtigger: To be honest, I think your answer is one of the better ones. I'm not familiar enough with EF to understand the ramifications of your proposal but I'm sure the OP would prefer a solution through c# over having to start diving into the SQL side of things.

Comment: @orgtigger Hey, I'm quiet because I'm evaluating all these answers, I will tell you as soon as I get through this.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues before where EF will decide to decorate the SQL it decides to run in a very non-performant fashion.

Anyways, to provide a possible solution to your question:

On instances where I don't like what EF does with my code to generate SQL statements, I end up writing a stored procedure, import that into my EDMX as a function and use that to retrieve my data. It affords me control on how to formulate the SQL and I know exactly what index I need to leverage to get the best performance out of this. I imagine you know how to write a stored proc and import that as a function into EF so I will leave those details out. Hope this helps you.

I will still keep checking this page to see if someone comes up with a nicer, less painful solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like somewhat obscure for me, And this is first time where I encounter such this querying. As you told, sometimes It takes too long time to execute, so it tells the query can be interpreted in another ways somewhere, perhaps by ignoring [EF performance considerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853) in some cases, So **try to rearrange query conditions/selections** and **consider lazy loading in your program logic**.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you bitten by the Statistic update problem in SQL server?

ALTER DATABASE YourDBName 
SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON

Default is OFF, thereby your SQL server will stall when 20% of your data has changed - waiting for the Statistics update before running the query.

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy, but it looks like you've got the thing ordering itself with itself when this code is called:

```
if (orderBy != null)
{
    query = orderBy(query);
}
```

I think that would explain the whole "sometimes it's slow" bit.  Probably runs fine until you have something in the `orderBy` parameter, then it's calling itself and creating that row numbered sub-select that slows it down.

Try commenting out the `query = orderBy(query)` portion of your code and see if you still get the slow down.  I'm betting that you won't.

Also, you can simplify your code using [Dynamic LINQ](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/).  It basically lets you specific sorting with a string name of a field (`.orderby("somefield")`) instead of trying to pass in a method, which I've found to be a lot easier.  I use that in MVC apps to handle sorting by whatever field the users clicks on a grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a non-clustered index on SentDate